# "Inbox" section of Stack Exchange icon not loading

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

After answering a couple of questions, I got the red circle in the top left corner of my screen telling me I had a comment, etc. But when I clicked on it, the "inbox" section did not display anything. The other sections, like "hot questions" worked fine. Is this a new bug?

[image: This is the image of my inbox]